# Bundler path problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, bundler

I've taken over ann application that was deployed to a server by someone else. There's something broken about the setup, some missing environment variable or similar problem but I am stumped. By the way this is obviously a Rails application, running under REE and mod_rails (passenger)

#### Here are some console logs that have me stumped. First, rake db:migrate claims I don't have Rails 2.3.8

```
$ rake db:migrate
(in /var/www/ems.trustthevote.org/ems/current)
Missing the Rails 2.3.8 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.8 rails`, update your      
RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.
```

#### However, bundler says I do:

```
$ bundle list
Gems included by the bundle:
[...snip]
  * actionmailer (2.3.8)
  * actionpack (2.3.8)
  * activerecord (2.3.8)
  * activeresource (2.3.8)
  * activesupport (2.3.8)
[...snip...]
  * rails (2.3.8)
```

#### But on the other hand, gem says no:

```
$ gem list rails

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
```

#### Here are some relevant environment variables:

```
RUBYOPT=-rauto_gem
RUBYLIB=~/.gem
```

And finally, here's what Ruby thinks:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> $:
=> ["~/.gem", "/usr/lib64/rubyee/site_ruby/1.8",     
"/usr/lib64/rubyee/site_ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux", "/usr/lib64/rubyee/site_ruby", 
"/usr/lib64/rubyee/vendor_ruby/1.8", "/usr/lib64/rubyee/vendor_ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux", 
"/usr/lib64/rubyee/vendor_ruby", "/usr/lib64/rubyee/1.8", "/usr/lib64/rubyee/1.8/x86_64   
linux", "."]
irb(main):002:0>
```

My eyes are crossed. What am I missing?

Comment: My dev environment as Mac OS X, and my deploy environment is Centos, running passenger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a custom bundle path, make sure that you run rake commands within the bundler environment.

`bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Try that out.

Comment: Hm... Not sure if I am using a custom bundle path. I don't think I set one up, do I get one 'for free'?

Comment: If you just used `bundle install` then the gems would appear in `gem list` - as they don't it must be using a custom path. The point is, using `bundle exec` will run the command with the bundle environment loaded, so all the gems seen by `bundle list` will be available.

Comment: I should probably point out that you can see where the gems are bundled is installed by looking at the `BUNDLE PATH` variable in RAILS_ROOT/.bundle/config, although that isn't really relevant to run the commands.

Answer (score 0):

Bundler installs the gem in a custom directory. This is the reason why the result of `gem list` won't show them.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure why the command `$ rake db:migrate` doesn't find your gems.

Comment: I am not sure whether I am in a custom directory... Do I get that by default?